# Log a message with a variable number of printf-style arguments

Tags: c#, logging, variadic-functions

I'm trying to implement a C# method that can log a message with a format string and a variable number of printf-style arguments.  Ideally, it would work identically to the C function I pasted below, although idiomatic to C# of course.

```
static
void
LogMessage(const char * iFormat, ...)
{
  va_list argp;
  FILE * fp;

  fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");
  if (fp != NULL) {
    va_start(argp, iFormat);
    vfprintf(fp, iFormat, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

This function is convenient for me, as it allows me to make the following calls:

```
LogMessage("Testing");
LogMessage("Testing %s", "1 2 3");
LogMessage("Testing %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
static void LogMessage(string format, params object[] args) {
    File.AppendAllText("log.txt", string.Format(format, args));
}

LogMessage("Testing {0} {1}", 1, "hi");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  I had some of the right elements, but just couldn't get them in the right "order"!

Answer (score 8):

You want to create a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

C# uses the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword to do this

```
static void LogMessage(string formatString, params string[] formatArguments)
{
    string.Format(formatString, formatArguments);
}
```

Please note that the params keyword can only be used on the **last** parameter in the method signature and that it requires the parameter to be an **array**.

This is merely syntactic sugar for actually passing an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void LogMessage(params string [] logList)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < logList.Length ; i++ )
       doLogging(logList[i]);
}
```